# Load files using thread C# wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I have a project in C#, it's called "Music Manager". When you choose a folder, the program will show all of music files in this folder, but if you have so much files in folder, the program will be crashes.

I think the solution is use thread, but I don't know how to use it? If anyone know, please help me. Thanks!

Comment: What code do you have at present?

Comment: you can reference this project at [link](http://github.com/longqnh/Music-Manager)

Comment: *****[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*****

Comment: You can use threads by simply using: `new Task(() => {...}).Start()` Where ... is a placeholder for code.

Comment: Post your code please, there is no reason that it will crash !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should specify the error message, but I don't think a thread would help you in this one, because i guess it crashes for an outofmemory (as it happens when there are a lot of files).

I've had a quick look at your project and i see you have a List populated from DirectoryInfo. Do you need all the fileinfo in a List? I suggest you use just a List and store only filename/path.

P.S. How many files do you have in your directory when it crashes? Just curious

Comment: If it's more than 500 files, the program will be crashed.
According to you, how can I solve it if I don't use thread?
Thanks